# Calculate average for several filters in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following data:

```
     date_  numbers_
2021-10-05         1
2021-10-08         3
2021-10-11         5
2021-10-14         7
2021-10-17         9
2021-10-20        11
2021-10-23        13
2021-10-26        15
2021-10-29        17
2021-11-01        19
```

which is produced by this piece of code:

```
select 
   date_, 
   numbers_
from (select generate_date_array('2021-10-05', '2021-11-01', interval 3 day) as date, generate_array(1, 20, 2) as numbers), 
unnest(date) as date_ with offset as pos1, unnest(numbers) as numbers_ with offset as pos2
where pos1 = pos2
```

What I want to do is to calculate the average of the `numbers_` field for the previous rows of **each date (even the ones missing)**. The result should be this:

```
     date_       avg
2021-10-05         1
2021-10-06         1
2021-10-07         1
2021-10-08         2
2021-10-09         2
2021-10-10         2
2021-10-11         3
2021-10-12         3
2021-10-13         3
2021-10-14         4
       ...       ...
```

It's like running the following piece of code, but for all dates in the `where` clause (`'2021-10-05'`, `'2021-10-06'`, `'2021-10-07'`, `'2021-10-08'`, ...):

```
with table_1 as (
  select 
    date_, 
    numbers_
  from (select generate_date_array('2021-10-05', '2021-11-01', interval 3 day) as date, generate_array(1, 20, 2) as numbers), 
  unnest(date) as date_ with offset as pos1, unnest(numbers) as numbers_ with offset as pos2
  where pos1 = pos2
  )

select
  avg(numbers_) as avg
from table_1
where date_ <= '2021-10-05'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider below:

```sql
WITH table_1 AS (
  select 
    date_, 
    numbers_
  from (select generate_date_array('2021-10-05', '2021-11-01', interval 3 day) as date, generate_array(1, 20, 2) as numbers), 
  unnest(date) as date_ with offset as pos1, unnest(numbers) as numbers_ with offset as pos2
  where pos1 = pos2
)
SELECT date_, AVG(numbers_) OVER (ORDER BY date_) avg
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-10-05', '2021-11-01')) date_
  LEFT JOIN table_1 USING (date_);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jaytiger. Is there any way to do this, if the date_ field is not available in the with clause?

Comment: @JamesHarrington, in order to calculate the moving average,  a column which defines an order of rows is needed. if your real data has any other column that replace **date_** column, I think you can apply above query using it with small modification.